# How to put KerasClassifier, Hyperopt and Sklearn cross-validation together

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation, hyperparameter-tuning

I am performing a hyperparameter tuning optimization (hyperopt) tasks with sklearn on a Keras models. I am trying to optimize KerasClassifiers using the Sklearn cross-validation, Some code follows:

```
def create_model():
model = Sequential()
model.add(
    Dense(output_dim=params['units1'],
          input_dim=features_.shape[1],
          kernel_initializer="glorot_uniform"))
model.add(Activation(params['activation']))
model.add(Dropout(params['dropout1']))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
...
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
```

Now what I want to do is to pass the Hyperopt params to KerasClassifier using the following way

```
def objective(params, n_folds=N_FOLDS):
"""Objective function for Hyperparameter Optimization"""

# Keep track of evals
global ITERATION

ITERATION += 1

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model,**params)

start = timer()

# Perform n_folds cross validation
cv_results = cross_val_score(clf,
                             features_,
                             labels,
                             cv=5
                             ).mean()

run_time = timer() - start

# Loss must be minimized
loss = -cv_results

# Dictionary with information for evaluation
return {
    'loss': loss,
    'params': params,
    'iteration': ITERATION,
    'train_time': run_time,
    'status': STATUS_OK
}
```

I define the search space as:

```
space = {
'units1':
hp.choice('units1', [64, 128, 256, 512]),
'units2':
hp.choice('units2', [64, 128, 256, 512]),
'dropout1':
hp.choice('dropout1', [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]),
'dropout2':
hp.choice('dropout2', [0.25, 0.5, 0.75]),
'batch_size':
hp.choice('batch_size', [10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100]),
'nb_epochs':
hp.choice('nb_epochs', [10, 50, 100]),
'optimizer':
opt_search_space,
'activation':
'relu'
```

}

Run optimization

```
best = fmin(fn = objective, space = space, algo = tpe.suggest, 
            max_evals = MAX_EVALS, trials = bayes_trials, rstate = np.random.RandomState(50))
```

But it fails giving this error:

```
ValueError: activation is not a legal parameter
```

What's the right way to do it?